# Ubuntu server routing table

Tags: networking, server, router, routing, nic

i've a ubuntu server (13.04) with 3 NICs.
This is my routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         vodafone.statio 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p1p1
192.168.8.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p2p2
192.168.17.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p2p1
```

The server is on the interet and sees the 2 subnets.
My PC is on subnet 17.xxx, i can ping all PCs on the subnet 8.xxx but i can't go on the internet.

How can i configure the routing table to redirect my request on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can ping from one subnet to another, there's no problem in your routing table. Probably packets from local networks are being sent to Internet unmodified. The problem is that [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) addresses are not routable through Internet.

Private network addresses must be [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT)'ed before sent to Internet. Try running:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o p1p1 -j MASQUERADE
```