# Routing in computing cluster

Tags: networking, server, routing, cluster

I'm trying to set up a computing cluster composed of four nodes. Each node have 2 interfaces `p1p1` and `p2p1`. The first node - head node - should be visible form the outer world. It should route all movement to and from slave nodes. Slave nodes should have internet connection via head node.

Head Node `/etc/network/interfaces`. I believe that last line is problematic.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto p1p1
    iface p1p1 inet static
    address 192.0.137.14
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    gateway 192.0.127.1
    dns-nameservers 194.0.61.14
    dns-search my.domain.com

auto p2p1
    iface p2p1 inet static
    address 10.10.10.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.10.10.0
    post-up route add -net 10.10.10.0/24 gw 10.10.10.1
```

Head Node routing table: `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.0.137.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p1p1
10.10.10.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p2p1
10.10.10.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p2p1
192.0.137.0     *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 p1p1
```

Slave Node `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto p1p1
iface p1p1 inet static
address 10.10.10.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.10.10.1
```

Slave Node routing table: `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p1p1
10.10.10.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p1p1
```

I can ssh from outer world to head node and again ssh from head node to slave node, but I cannot ping anything from slave node. It doesn't matter if I ping domain name or IP address.

System:

```
root@troll-0:/home/michal# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I found also this: [Ubuntu server routing table](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318898/ubuntu-server-routing-table) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto p1p1
    iface p1p1 inet static
    address 192.0.137.14
    netmask 255.255.255.224
    gateway 192.0.127.1
```

Your gateway 192.0.**127**.1 outside of your network. 192.0.**137**.14/27

Comment: and drop `post-up route add -net 10.10.10.0/24 gw 10.10.10.1` it's not needed also did you enable IP forwarding on the head node? should have **net.ipv4.ip_forward=1** in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: I intentionally changed the addresses to avoid malignancy, but they where correct. Setting ``net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`` was a part what I needed. The second part was setting iptables:
``sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE``
``sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state -–state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT``
``sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT``
Thank you :)